# What is NASCII?

Tags: python, regex

While reviewing code for [spell](https://github.com/logforensicator/spell/blob/master/spell.py), I cam across `line = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '<NASCII>', line)`. From [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.compile), It appears that it is looking for hexadecimal numbers but I am unclear what it is replacing them with. Is it suggesting that the hexadecimal values represent ASCII numbers? I couldn't find any reference to NASCII online that made sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The replacement is the literal string `'<NASCII>'`. Whatever it stands for in the original context of the code you found it in is open for guesses

Comment: **N**ot **A**SCII

Comment: It looks like a trick to replace non ascii characters so they won't mess up the matching. https://github.com/logforensicator/spell/blob/master/spell.py#L313

Comment: "It appears that it is looking for hexadecimal numbers" - no, it's `\x{number}`, that is a character with number of `{number}`. As you can see, it's hex 00-7F so literally half a block - ascii is only lower, upper are used in other encodings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is just literally the string `<NASCII>`.

notice the `^` at the start of the pattern, it looks for everything that NOT `\x00-\x7f`, (which is 0-127) so basically, not ascii...

Comment: And, here, "ASCII" means the subset of characters in common with ASCII in whichever character set the string uses is using (see [Python String](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type)), not the actual ASCII character set itself. Such a subset is also known as [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The ASCII character set indeed comprises the character codes 0x00 through 0x7F (decimal 0-127). The regex matches any sequence of characters not in this set (not the hex characters - `'\xab'` is a Python escape code which matches the character whose character code is 0xAB, or decimal 172) with the literal string `<NASCII>`, presumably to identify it as "not ASCII" in a vaguely human-readable form.